# 2 query occurrence errors

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

When this form is processed, 2 query is generated.

In query 1: all data is successful but with the exception of the picture. picture: it sounds worth "NULL".

query 2: the picture is written correctly. but other data is being written "NULL".

What I want is that instead of query 2, the image data in query 2 should come to query 1 and only 1 query should be formed.

## This is My Controller And Model

```
public function send_Basvur_message(){

$this->load->library("form_validation");
$this->load->model("Basvur_model");

$this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "Ad", "trim|required");
$this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "E-posta", "trim|required|valid_email");
$this->form_validation->set_rules("subject", "Konu", "trim|required");
$this->form_validation->set_rules("message", "Mesaj", "trim|required");
$this->form_validation->set_rules("url", "url");
$this->form_validation->set_rules("captcha", "Doğrulama Kodu", "trim|required");

$path = './panel/uploads/basvur_v/';
$initialize = $this->upload->initialize(array(
    "upload_path" => $path,
    "allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp",
    "remove_spaces" => TRUE
));
$imagename = 'no-img.jpg';
$config['max_size'] = 51200;
$config['overwrite'] = false;
$config['encrypt_name'] = false;
$config['remove_space'] = false;
$imagename = 'no-img.jpg';


if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
} else if(!$this->upload->do_upload('img_url')) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Action Completed');
    redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
} else {

    $insert = $this->Basvur_model->add(
        array(
            "name"          => $this->input->post("name"),
            "email"         => $this->input->post("email"),
            "message"       => $this->input->post("message"),
            "subject"       => $this->input->post("subject"),
            "url"           => $imagename,
            "created_at"    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        )
    );
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $imagename = $data['file_name'];
    $this->Basvur_model->setURL($imagename);            
    $this->Basvur_model->create();                           
    $this->session->set_flashdata('img_uploaded', $imagename);

    if($this->session->userdata("captcha") == $this->input->post("captcha")){

        $name = $this->input->post("name");
        $email = $this->input->post("email");
        $subject = $this->input->post("subject");
        $message = $this->input->post("message");


        $email_message = "{$name} isimli ziyaretçi. Başvuru Yaptı <br><b>Mesaj : </b> {$message} <br> <b>E-posta : </b> {$email}";

        if(send_email("", "Yeni Aday başvurusu | $subject", $email_message)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
            redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
            // TODO Alert..
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
            redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
            // TODO Alert..
        }

    } else {
        //başarısıs
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Action Not Completed');
    redirect(base_url("basvuru"));

    }
}
}
```

## Model

```
    <?php

class Basvur_model extends CI_Model
{

    public $tableName = "basvurs";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

        private $_ID;
    private $_url;

    public function setID($ID) {
        $this->_ID = $ID;
    }

    public function setURL($url) {
        $this->_url = $url;
    }
    // get image
    public function getPicture() {        
        $this->db->select(array('p.id', 'p.url'));
        $this->db->from('basvurs p');  
        $this->db->where('p.id', $this->_ID);     
        $query = $this->db->get();
       return $query->row_array();
    }
    // insert image
    public function create() { 
        $data = array(
            'url' => $this->_url,
        );
        $this->db->insert('basvurs', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    

    public function get($where = array())
    {
        return $this->db->where($where)->get($this->tableName)->row();
    }

    /** Tüm Kayıtları bana getirecek olan metot.. */
    public function get_all($where = array(), $order = "id ASC")
    {
        return $this->db->where($where)->order_by($order)->get($this->tableName)->result();
    }

    public function add($data = array())
    {
        return $this->db->insert($this->tableName, $data);
    }

    public function update($where = array(), $data = array())
    {
        return $this->db->where($where)->update($this->tableName, $data);  
    }

    public function delete($where = array())
    {
        return $this->db->where($where)->delete($this->tableName);
    }

}
```

Comment: you make reference to table 1 and table 2 in your code but I don't see that anywhere, nor do I see multiple db tables being used in the create function. please narrow down your code to only what is relevant and make a clearer description/problem statement as an *edit* to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry I mixed the terms, I meant the query, not the table. 2 queries occur when the form is processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to query 1 in your code you will notice that:

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
$imagename = $data['file_name'];
```

isn't populated until after your insert `$insert` statement. Move it before.

With regards to your second query, I'm not sure what is being populated as NULL however the only variable you are sending to the query is the url.

```
 public function create() { 
        $data = array(
            'url' => $this->_url,
        ); // see just this^
        $this->db->insert('basvurs', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Now all of this data seems to go in to the same table? I'm not sure why you don't just do it all in one insert statement. It is also a bit confusing why you'd want duplicate entries.